# Android google map turn-by-turn navigation issue

Tags: android, google-maps

I am implementing an app that provide navigation from current location to another. For that I have used Google turn-by-turn navigation. But some devices show different end points for the same address. I have attached screenshots of two different devices. The destination address is 5121 Rhoads Avenue, Santa barbara, CA, USA

This is the code I'm using

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=5121 Rhoads Avenue, Santa barbara, CA, USA");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

Device A results

[image: device A end point]
[image: device A direction steps]

Device B results

[image: device B end point]

[image: device B direction steps]

Comment: show code what you have tried.

Comment: I have add the code